# getting pid of two last commands executed in background and do stuff

Tags: bash, process, kill, background-process, pid

I wrote this bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

    eval "(a command) &"
    pid1=$!

    eval "(while kill -0 $pid1; do .... ; done) &"  #It creates file.txt after few seconds
    pid2=$!

    if [ -s /tmp/file.txt ]; then
             for line in $(cat /tmp/file.txt)
                 do
                  sth
                 done
```

With logic of bash scripting: Is the values of pid1 and pid2 correct?

Is this script running correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need the `eval "(...) &" syntax. Simply do this instead:

```
cmd1 &
pid1=$!

cmd2 &
pid2=$!
```

But otherwise your approach looks OK to me.

#### Example

```
$ more ex.bash 
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10 &
pid1=$!

sleep 10 &
pid2=$!

echo "ID1: $pid1 --- ID2: $pid2"
```

Now when I run it:

```
$ ./ex.bash 
ID1: 27866 --- ID2: 27867
```

We can confirm this is correct:

```
$ pgrep -l sleep
27866 sleep
27867 sleep
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used `eval` because my commands are long and quite complicated...

Comment: So my while loop with the condition `kill -0 $pid1` is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @MortezaLSC - seems reasonable to me.